# Alternative for google "less secure apps" for python3 script

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

I am using google mail for a Python3 script to send mail via SMTP. This worked until 05/30 via "access less secure apps" in google mail settings. I was able to send emails via smtp.gmail.com using my script this way. Now [google has discontinued this setting](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=5&hl=en&authuser=5&visit_id=637910649406992323-1779868349&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1#zippy=%2Capp-passwort-verwenden).
What would be the easiest alternative to allow my script to send mails again?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it myself.
Just enable MFA and then you can generate apps passwords. Works. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).